# i18n in NextJS always has default of 'en' despite config file

Tags: next.js, i18next

I have a project in NextJS where I am using i18n and everything works fine except for when I enter the site where translation is supposed to be in 'sr', but for some reason, Next routes to 'en'. Here's my config file

```
const i18nConfig = {
  locales: ["sr", "en"],
  defaultLocale: "sr",
  localeDetection: false,
  serverLanguageDetection: false,
  browserLanguageDetection: false,
  domains: [
    {
      domain: "http://207.154.239.161:3002",
      defaultLocale: "sr",
    },
    {
      domain: "https://localhost:3002",
      defaultLocale: "sr",
    },
  ],
};

module.exports = i18nConfig;
```